# Closing child Form causes Parent Form to lose focus

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a simple form with a button `Button1` that, once pressed, it opens a new `_frm` as follows:

```
Protected _frm As Form
[...]
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      _frm = New Form()
      AddHandler _frm.Deactivate, AddressOf OnFormDeactivated
      AddHandler _frm.FormClosed, AddressOf OnFormClosed
      With _frm
         .Location = PointToScreen(New Point(0, Height))
         .Text = "_frm"
         .Show(Me.FindForm)
      End With
End Sub
```

And the handlers for the `Deactivate` and `FormClosed` events are defined as follows:

```
Private Sub OnFormDeactivated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
      _frm.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub OnFormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs)
      Me.FindForm.RemoveOwnedForm(_frm)

      RemoveHandler _frm.Deactivate, AddressOf OnFormDeactivated
      RemoveHandler _frm.FormClosed, AddressOf OnFormClosed

      _frm.Dispose()
      _frm = Nothing

      WindowUtil.ShowWindow(Process.GetCurrentProcess) 'call to user32.dll ShowWindow
      WindowUtil.ToForeground(Process.GetCurrentProcess) 'call to user32.dll SetForegroundWindow
End Sub
```

When I close the child Form, the Parent form gets the focus back and the same is true if I select another application, which is the **desired** behaviour.
But if I click anywhere inside the Parent Form, the Child Form disappears correctly but the Parent Form (and therefore the entire application) loses focus.

**EDIT**
`WindowUtil.vb` methods:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetForegroundWindow",
                 CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall,
                  CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function SetForegroundWindow(ByVal handle As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

Public Shared Sub ToForeground(proc As Process)
         Dim ForegroundReturn As Boolean = SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle)
End Sub

<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="ShowWindow",
                 CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall,
                 CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function ShowWindow(ByVal handle As IntPtr, ByVal nCmd As Int32) As Boolean
End Function

Public Shared Sub ShowWindow(proc As Process)
         Dim ShowReturn As Boolean = ShowWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong about what "focus" means. I keep saying that it hasn't got the focus because, in the taskbar, the icon of the app is not highlighted. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to add a delay between the `BringToFront()` / `Activate()` methods calls and the `Form.Close()` call that closes the owned Form: it should give more *stable* results in both situations: when you click the Owner Form and when you click a Window that belongs to another application.

As a note:

- [Control.BringToFront()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,5611) is actually calling the [SetWindowPos()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) function.
- [Form.Activate()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,3082) is actually a call to [SetForegroundWindow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow)

That's why PInvoking is not *necessary* (meaning, the Framework already does this for you).

`Form.Close()` is called after the the activation of the Owner Form because this causes the Control (in the Owner Form) that receives the mouse action to become the `ActiveControl`, without setting this property explicitly.

► The `15` milliseconds delay can be fine-tuned, since the *nature* of the Form (how it's built and how many Controls it contains) can affect the time it needs to close (because `OwnerForm.Activate()` is called right before returning from the async `ActivateForm()` method and the Form on top is closed right after).
This generates a *smoother transition*, but it may also cause the Owner Form to *blink* when you click the Window that belongs to another Process.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   ' someForm is clearly a made-up class name :) Set it to actual the class name.
    Dim frm As New someForm()
    AddHandler frm.Deactivate, AddressOf OnFormDeactivated
    With frm
        ' Whatever this means to you
        .Location = PointToScreen(New Point(0, Height))
        .Text = "frm"
        .Show(Me)
    End With
End Sub

Private Async Sub OnFormDeactivated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim frm = DirectCast(sender, Form)
    RemoveHandler frm.Deactivate, AddressOf OnFormDeactivated
    Await ActivateForm(Me)
    frm.Close()
End Sub

Private Async Function ActivateForm(frm As Form) As Task
    Await Task.Delay(15)
    frm.BringToFront()
    Await Task.Delay(15)
    frm.Activate()
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solution works in my little test application. Now I have to understand why it doesn't in the full one.

Comment: I managed to fix the bug that was causing the problem in the full project. Thanks a lot for the help and patiance.